# MaterialDatePicker error: materialCalendarFullscreenTheme attribute to be set in your app theme

Tags: android, datepicker, material-components-android

What I did:

1. Added `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'` in dependencies
2. Set `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge` as parent to app theme

```
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

3. Tried to show date picker in fragment.

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020);
        now.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);

        long first = now.getTimeInMillis();

        now.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020);
        now.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
        now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);

        long last = now.getTimeInMillis();

        builder.setSelection(new Pair<>(first, last));

        MaterialDatePicker<Pair<Long, Long>> picker = builder.build();

        picker.show(fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "RangePicker");
```

**When I ran the code, got this error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker
requires a value for the com.example:attr/materialCalendarFullscreenTheme attribute to be set
in your app theme. You can either set the attribute in your theme or update your theme to
inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Just add the following to your app theme.

```
<item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
<item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
<item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
```

#### After adding

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

   <!-- Add these -->
   <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
   <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
   <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you should migrate to the new `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` themes without the `Bridge` suffix which should automatically include the themes and styles needed.

Comment: Using either of the above themes made my Tab bar lose its effects and the non-selected tab text invisible. Not good.

Instead, extend your AppTheme from Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar.Bridge 
or, light instead of DayNight...

Comment: `materialCalendarStyle` should be **attr**, not **item**

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution ! Just make sure the theme.xml is the same theme that you used in manifest file part theme.
In android manifest:
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
in theme.xml:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).