# MaterialCalendar datePicker appear distorted

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-datepicker

My date picker appear crooked if my AppTheme doesn't inherit directly from "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar".

[image]

I was trying to do a material bridge to apply new style to all view elements so I won't have to do it manually.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
    <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/MaterialCalendar</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialCalendar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponent">
```

But it doesn't work, the view is displayed wrong, am I missing something?

Like I said, the following is the output I'm looking for, but currently only get it when my app theme parent is this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

[image]

Comment: It seems it was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60870677/materialdatepicker-error-materialcalendarfullscreentheme-attribute-to-be-set-in